# Intellij and Resolve Reference via Mouse, not Alt-Enter

Tags: intellij-idea

when I have class/method/whatever

```
public void DoSomething(MyObject obj)
{
}
```

and i don't have an import statement for "MyObject"....

with intelliJ, you can kinda hover over the code "MyObject" and (eventually, when I rub the genie just right).... it'll say "use the Alt-Enter keys to attempt the resolution of this unknown" (it doesn't really say that, but that is the gist)

(or instead of Alt-key...it'll have that _ key with intellij on Mac) and that allows a menu item to come up to do the import.

Is there a right-click version or this?  or menu item version of this? aka, a MOUSE version of this?

The "hover over" seems so fickle.  It drives me nuts.

IntelliJ version 2017.3 or .4

Comment: Why is Alt-Enter not good for you?

Comment: Some people prefer keyboard short cuts.  Some people prefer mouse.

Comment: I couldn't find a feature request like that, so I'd suggest to file one on https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue

Comment: Thank you for considering and providing a hint to feature request.